# R script using YAML config

Tags: r, yaml

I am trying to run a .R script using a YAML config file. What is the syntax within the R console for me to be able to run the R script using an specific YAML config file?

Thanks..

Comment: Do you want to parse a YAML file? I'm sorry, but I do not understand what do you mean under "run the R script using an specific YAML config file".

Comment: We have functional level code which is contained within a R script (script.R), which employs YAML config files, e.g.:
 "emr:
 aws_access_key_id: ?
 aws_secret_access_key: ?
 ec2_core_instace_type: ?
 num_ec2_core_instances: ?
 r_instances_per_node: ?
 input:
 etc..

 What would be the syntax to execute the R script using the YAML config file?

Comment: For parsing YAML, you need the [yaml R package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/yaml/), especially the `yaml.load` function

Comment: Right so I have already loaded the yaml R package and execute the steps below in the R console

library(yaml)
config <- yaml.load_file('location_of_yaml_file')

source('location_of_r_script')
run

Get the error below.. 

Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") : cannot open file 'NA': No such file or directory

Comment: In addition, when I try to run the script from a terminal using a Rscript I get the error below.  


Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
Calls: run ... yaml.load_file -> yaml.load -> paste -> readLines -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") : cannot open file 'NA': No such file or directory
Execution halted

Comment: If you do not post a question with a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/564164), it's rather hard to help. SO is not a support forum, but you have to do your homework with either reading and interpreting your error/warning messages, or to produce a minimal demo, so that the community can try and debug the problem at localhost. Anyway, in short: I suspect that you have a path issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working the .The R script creates a function where you can input the config file to use.

Thanks..

Comment: Would have been nice if the answer included a working example of your solution.